# List all user accounts with an active presence on the local device

Tags: windows, powershell, user-accounts

I need a way in PowerShell (ideally PS2.0+) to list all user accounts on a local system where a user has a local presence, but where users may not be *local users* per se. That is to say that the device may be connected to a domain, where a command like `get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount` will list *all users on the domain* and (most likely) either time out or run into a permissions error because the command is being run from the context of the local user (even if it is being executed as the LocalSystem account).

Here are the various ways I know of to enumerate users and why they are inappropriate.

- `get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter {LocalAccount="True"}`
  This doesn't show domain users who have actually logged into the device; it only shows users who have been set up locally on the device in question, leaving potential user accounts on the table.
- `net user`
  As above.
- `get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount` (with no additional arguments)
  On devices connected to a suitably large domain, this query hangs and eventually exits with a "task cancelled" error as it is trying to enumerate several thousands of users. I only need the users with a presence on the local device.
- Enumerate `HKEY_USERS`
  This hive only enumerates as keys the profiles of users who are logged-in *at the time of the query*.
- Enumerate `C:\Users`
  This works, but I am loth to use it; it feels so imprecise. Further, it also adds useless accounts like `Default` and `Public` which I'm not interested in.

I will attempt to pre-empt complaints like [the response to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433344/3281030) ("then you need to redesign your application") by noting that *I am not attempting to gather data* from these User Profiles. All I need is to enumerate them; an accountName value is quite sufficient.
Is there a ledger or roster somewhere within Windows that I can query for this data beyond looking at folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` contains subkeys for all accounts that have a user profile directory known to Windows. Everyone in the local "Users" group has Read permissions for this key.

The subkeys are named after account SIDs, which you can map to a username using [existing APIs](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2776-powershell-sid-to-user-and-user-to-sid):

```
$sidobj = [Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] $sidstr
$namestr = $sidobj.Translate([Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```

Use the [known SIDs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers) table to filter out unwanted "internal account" SIDs or SID-prefixes. (Generally the SIDs of all "real" accounts start with `S-1-5-21-`.)

Comment: THIS IS PERFECT! Thank you. You genius.